# Postman stuck while requesting the express GET request

Tags: node.js, express, http, postman

I am using expressJs and trying to hit with postman but postman got stuck here is my code
I dont know why it is doing that, previously it was working totally fine.
can someone help me out please?

```
//Role controller
const Role = require("../Models/Role");

const getAllRoles = (req, res, next) => {
  Role.find({})
    .populate("permissions")
    .then(
      (roles) => {
        res
          .status(200)
          .json({ success: true, message: "Role retrieved", data: roles });
      },
      (err) => next(err)
    )
    .catch(() => next(new Error("Can't retrieve all roles")));
};

const createRole = (req, res, next) => {
  const newRole = new Role({
    title: req.body.title,
    permissions: req.body.permissions,
  });
  Role.create(newRole)
    .then(
      (role) => {
        res
          .status(201)
          .json({ success: true, message: "Role created", data: role });
      },
      (err) => next(err)
    )
    .catch(() => next(new Error("Couldnot Create Role")));
};

const updateRole = (req, res, next) => {
  Role.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: req.body }, { new: true })
    .then(
      () => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.json({ success: true, message: "role updated" });
      },
      (err) => next(err)
    )
    .catch((err) => next(err));
};

const deleteRole = async (req, res, next) => {
  const role = await Role.findById(req.params.id);
  if (!role) {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.json({ success: true, message: "role is already deleted" });
  }
  Role.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    .then(
      () => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.json({ success: true, message: "role deleted" });
      },
      (err) => next(err)
    )
    .catch((err) => next(err));
};

module.exports = {
  createRole,
  deleteRole,
  getAllRoles,
  updateRole,
};

//roleRouter
const express = require("express");

const roleRouter = express.Router();

const roleController = require("../Controller/roleController");

roleRouter.get("/", roleController.getAllRoles);
roleRouter.post("/", roleController.createRole);
roleRouter.patch("/:id", roleController.updateRole);
roleRouter.delete("/:id", roleController.deleteRole);

module.exports = roleRouter;

//app.js
const express = require("express");
const createError = require("http-errors");
const path = require("path");
require("dotenv/config");

const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

const expresssession = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");

// const redisClient = require("./middleware/redisClient")
const responseTime = require("response-time")
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
const swaggerJSDoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("./middleware/passport");
const UserRouter = require("./Routes/UsersRouter");
const env = require("./configs/dev");
const roleRouter = require("./Routes/RoleRouter");
const permissionRouter = require("./Routes/PermissionRouter");

const url = env.mongoUrl;
const connect = mongoose.connect(url);

connect.then(
  () => {
    console.log("connected Correctly");
  },
  (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  }
);


app.use(
  expresssession({
    secret: env.secrectKey,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongoUrl: env.mongoUrl }),
  })
);
app.use(cors({ origin: "*" }));
app.use(express.static("./assets"));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(responseTime);

const swaggerOptions = {
  definition: {
    openapi: "3.0.0",
    info: {
      title: "Green-Me Official",
      version: "0.1.0",
      description: "API Routes and Database Schema for GreenMe-Official",
    },
    servers: [
      {
        url: `http://${env.host}/${env.port}`,
      },
    ],
  },
  apis: ["src/routes/UsersRouter.js"],
};
const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(swaggerOptions);

app.get("/api-docs.json", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  res.send(swaggerSpec);
});
app.use(
  "/api-docs",
  swaggerUi.serve,
  swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec, { explorer: true })
);

app.use("/role", roleRouter);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(createError(404));
});

/

module.exports = app;
```

I have given my 3 files code. one is app.js its the main file, other is my router and controller file. I am unable to hit 'http:localhost:5000/role' it just got stuck postman.

Comment: What do you mean by “got stuck”? Does postman give an error? If so, upload it here. If the server isn’t receiving anything, you should state that.

Comment: no, it doesn't give error it just keep sending the request and never returns neither response neither error

Comment: I can’t tell how good your logging is. You should check if the server is receiving any requests.

Comment: how can i check that if my server is receiving any request?

Comment: Add logging with console.log where a request is handled.